# Javascripts equivalente to PHP's GET variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I am coding javascript in node.js, I would like to use javascripts equivalent of PHP's:

```
$somevar = $_GET["1234"];
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using express.js? If so, then in the request callback use req.query

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello ' + req.query["name"]);
});
```

mysite.com/?name=world

outputs: hello world

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I will use express.js.